# electron - window.postMessage to talk between preload and renderer with specific target origin

Tags: electron

I would like to validate/differentiate the origin of a message using the `targetOrigin` of `postMessage` between `preload.js` and `renderer.js` with contextIsolation enabled.

So if a message come from `preload.js`, the originTarget being something like `file://preload.js`, and from renderer `file://renderer.js`.

Setting `file://preload.js` or `file://renderer.js`, make the error `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('file://').`.

Does someone know how to achieve what I’m trying to achieve?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#Using_window.postMessage_in_extensions):

> Lastly, posting a message to a page at a `file:` URL currently requires that the `targetOrigin` argument be `"*"`. `file://` cannot be used as a security restriction; this restriction may be modified in the future.

So in `preload.js` you need to use `*` as `targetOrigin`:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  window.postMessage({ type: "fooType", text: "barMsg" }, "*")
})
```

In the receiving renderer (webpage), restrict message processing to `file://` scheme and `window` object reference for security reasons:

```js
window.addEventListener(
  "message",
  event => {
    if (event.origin === "file://" && event.source === window) {
      console.log(event.data)
    }
  },
  false
)
```

This will also work with a more restrictive config as follows (`webPreferences` for `BrowserWindow`):

```json
{
  nodeIntegration: false,
  contextIsolation: true,
  enableRemoteModule: false,
  preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
}
```